# Imprimir còdigo de barras en una tabla

Tags: php, pdf, php5, fpdf

Estoy diseñando un reporte en php con fpdf y necesito imprimir el codigo de barras asociado a un pedido, este listado contiene los datos de los pedidos que son enviados a despacho (manifiesto) El problema es que no logro que la  libreria Code39 me funcione cada vez qye la llamo dentro del for que dibuja la tabla, simplemente arroja un ERROR 500 y nada mas, la pagina se queda en blanco.
[image: el reporte que quiero]

y el còdigo

```html
    $sql = "SELECT 
                        A.PEDIDO_WEB_LARGO AS PEDIDO,
                        UPPER(D.neighborhood) AS COMUNA, 
                        
                        CASE WHEN ISNULL( D.description, '') != '' THEN 
                            UPPER(CONCAT(D.street,' ', D.number, 'DEPTO/CASA.: ', D.description)) 
                        ELSE 
                            UPPER(CONCAT(D.street,' ', D.number))
                        END 
                        AS DIRECCION,
                        UPPER(REPLACE(C.cardname, ';', '' )) AS CLIENTE,
                        C.Phone     AS TELEFONO 
                    
                    FROM [Report].[dbo].[MANIFIESTO_OTROS] M 
                    INNER JOIN MOD_WEB A ON A.ID_MOD_WEB = M.ID_MOD_WEB 
                    INNER JOIN DIRECCIONES_JSON_VTEX D ON D.pedido_web = A.PEDIDO_WEB_LARGO 
                    INNER JOIN CLIENTES_WEB C ON C.cardcode = A.RUT_CLIENTE 
                    WHERE NRO_MANIFIESTO = '".$id."' ";

  $resultado = mssql_query($sql);
    $registros = mssql_num_fields($resultado);
    $estado="";
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($resultado))
    {   
        $pdf->Cell(40,7, $this->Code39(0,7,'CODE 39',1,10), 1, 0, 'C',true);
        $pdf->Cell(30,7,"".utf8_decode($row['COMUNA'])."",1,0,'L',true);
        $pdf->Cell(105,7,"".utf8_decode($row['DIRECCION'])."",1,0,'L',true);
        $pdf->Cell(70,7,"".utf8_decode($row['CLIENTE'])."",1,0,'L',true);
        $pdf->Cell(25,7,"".$row['TELEFONO']."",1,0,'C',true);
        $pdf->Ln();
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Hola Virginia. Nunca he utilizado esta librería, Code39. Pero aquí mis consejos: 1) veo que añades celdas, pero no veo donde has creado la tabla o insertas nuevas filas (puede que sea la línea `$pdf->Ln()`?) 2) no tienes que indicar que en la primera celda va una imagen en vez de texto? Y 3) Intenta crear un pdf solo con el primer código de barras, nada mas. Luego, solo todos los códigos de barras. Y después ve metiendo el resto.

Comment: Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta el mensaje de error completo. No sabemos qué error te da

Comment: @jotaelesalinas Gracias por la sugerencia, lo harè.  Esta todo el còdigo del fpdf pero no lo puedo incluir porque se hace muy largo

Comment: @Alfabravo como lo indico en la consulta solo da ERROR 500 no indica nada mas

Comment: En los logs del servidor no sale nada más?

Comment: @Virginia FPDF tiene la capacidad de escribir código `HTML`, puedes intentar dibujar la tabla tal como se haría en `HTML` con `PHP` y luego usar `$pdf->WriteHTML('Aqui va tu HTML')`